# Basis and generators of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having a doubt about the difference of a basis and a family of generators of a vector space.

Say I have $\mathbb{R}^{30}$.
I know that there are at most $30$ linearly independent vectors; its canonical basis is made by exactly $30$ vectors.

What about the generators? I don't know if I understood well, but I got this: a basis is a sequence of linearly independent vectors through which all other vectors can be written /built.

A family of generators, "generate" the vector space we work in, but they could be more than the dimension of the vector space we work in (there are simply certain linearly dependent vectors), so for example could I have $40$ generators.

Am I right? Or I understood nothing...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a radical example is this: a set of a generators of every vector space $V$ is the set $V$ itself. In turns out that every set of generators of a $n$-dimensional vector space has (at least) $n$ elements. Actually, in such a vector space $V$ every set of generators contains a basis of $V$. And every set that contains a basis is a set of generators.

Comment: So if I undersand well, I can take, say, the $30$ vectors of the canonical basis, and then I can add many other vectors, which will be linear combinations of the canonical basis. That would still generate $\mathbb{R}^{30}$, but clearly wouldn't be a base. Right?

Comment: Yes you are right !